# How to verify the domain when integrating google sign In in Mobile App?

Tags: android, ios, oauth, google-signin, google-api-console

I do have one app which uses **google Sign In**.
On the google API console under OAuth Consent Screen, I have updated my app logo and because of it, It started showing a warning to get the app verified.

Now under Authorized domains I can see something like
[image: THIS]

Now I am not sure how I can get the firebase domain verified which is definitely of my app.

Answer (score -2):

In order for your app to be verified and be in production you must prove to google you own the domains for which you are connecting to.

> When a domain is used on the consent screen or in an OAuth client’s configuration, it must be pre-registered here. If your app needs to go through verification, please go to the [Google Search](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) Console to check if your domains are authorized. Learn more about the authorized [domain limit](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7650096).

So if you own firebaseapp.com you will need to set it up on search console to prove your ownership.